# Module scikit_learn not found even after installation

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have installed the scikit_learn module with `pip install scikit_learn` in Spyder and got the message:

```
Requirement already satisfied: scikit_learn in c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (0.24.1)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy>=1.13.3 in c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit_learn) (1.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: threadpoolctl>=2.0.0 in c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit_learn) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: joblib>=0.11 in c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit_learn) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy>=0.19.1 in c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from scikit_learn) (1.6.2)
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.
```

However, when I run `import scikit_learn` afterwards I get the `ModuleNotFoundError`. Weirdly enough I don't see a `scikit_learn` folder in the path `c:\users\ycr700\anaconda3\lib\site-packages`, which I do for other packages.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Some python modules have different names between `pip install` and `import`, this is one of them. Use `import sklearn` instead.

It's always worth checking out the [getting started guides](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/getting_started.html) if the module has one to look for things like this.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Kindly refrain from answering questions that are essentially due to typos (they are unlikely to be helpful for others in the future) - flag them for closure as such instead.

Comment: @desertnaut I'd argue that this isn't just down to typos - it's not immediately clear that you can't use the same name for `import` and `pip install` with every module, and I can definitely see it being an issue for new users of python that no amount of proofreading will fix